# How to fix [unexpected token "indent"] error in pug?

Tags: pug

```
Error: /home/user/Desktop/app/backend/views/register.pug:2:1
    1|  doctype html
  > 2|  html
-------^
    3|    head
    4|      title = title
    5|    body

unexpected token "indent"
    at makeError (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug-error/index.js:32:13)
    at Parser.error (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug-parser/index.js:53:15)
    at Parser.parseExpr (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug-parser/index.js:264:14)
    at Parser.parse (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug-parser/index.js:112:25)
    at parse (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug-parser/index.js:12:20)
    at Object.parse (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:125:22)
    at Function.loadString [as string] (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug-load/index.js:45:21)
    at compileBody (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:86:18)
    at Object.exports.compile (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:242:16)
    at handleTemplateCache (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:215:25)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:427:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/shivtaj/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:417:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:464:11)
    at View.render (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/user/Desktop/app/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pug is very sensitive to indentation.  The error message above indicates that you have a space character ahead of the `html` tag and it doesn't like that.

Move the `doctype html` and `html` lines to the very left, so there's no whitespace in front of them.  Then, make sure the other lines are indented properly (two spaces to indent) otherwise you'll see indentation errors on the remaining lines.